# Gatsby with Apollo gives error as Client in undefined in Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, gatsby

My component also uses gatsby...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import axios from 'axios'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'

export const IndexQuery = gql`
{
  allsingleCsv {
    make
    model
    image
    _variant
    ex_showroom_price
    path
}
}`

class CarTemplatePage extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name : '',
      number : 0,
      emailId : ''
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this)
    this.onNumberChange = this.onNumberChange.bind(this)
    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("user_id", "44");
    data.append("city", "Bangalore");
    data.append("lead_category_id", "1");
    data.append("lead_type_id", "1");
    data.append("lead_source_id", "3");
    data.append("make_id", "11");
    data.append("model_id", "11");
    data.append("vehicle_id", "601");
    data.append("services_id", "1");
    data.append("status", "0");

    const header = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    }

    axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/v1/dealers/leads',
      method: 'post',
      headers: header,
      data: data
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data)
    });
  }

  onNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  onNumberChange(event) {
    this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ emailId: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const IMAGE_URL = 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/carsonline.in/';
    // const data = [...this.props.data.allsingleCsv]

    return (

             <Query ssr={true} query={IndexQuery}>
               {({loading, error, data}) => {
                    if (loading) return null;
                    if (error) throw err;
                   return console.log(data);
                }}
            </Query>

        </div>



<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='container'>
<div className="form-group">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input type="Name" className="form-control" id="Name" onChange={this.onNameChange} value={this.state.name}/>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label for="Contact Number">Contact Number:</label>
  <input type="Contact Number" className="form-control" id="contactNumber" onChange={this.onNumberChange} value={this.state.number}/>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label for="Email Id">Email ID:</label>
  <input type="Email Id" className="form-control" id="EmailId" onChange={this.onEmailChange} value={this.state.emailId}/>
</div>
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
      </div>


    )
  }
}
export default CarTemplatePage;
```

This is gatsby ssr

```
/**
 * Implement Gatsby's SSR (Server Side Rendering) APIs in this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/
 */

 // You can delete this file if you're not using it
 import React from "react";
 import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
 import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from "apollo-client";
 import { ApolloProvider, getDataFromTree } from "react-apollo";
 import { ServerStyleSheet, StyleSheetManager } from "styled-components";
 import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
 import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

 // function to generate hydrated state for client side Apollo
 function makeApolloState(ssrClient) {
   const state = { apollo: ssrClient.getInitialState() }
   // appends apollo state to the global client window object
   return (
     <script
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
         __html: `window.__APOLLO_STATE__=${JSON.stringify(state).replace(
           /</g,
           `\\u003c`
         )};`
       }}
     />
   );
 }

//appollo setup
const link = new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' });
 // Apollo client in server side rendering mode
 const client = new ApolloClient({
   link,
   ssrMode: true,
   dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
 });

 exports.replaceRenderer = ({
   bodyComponent,
   replaceBodyHTMLString,
   setHeadComponents
 }) =>
   new Promise((resolve) => {
     // bodyComponent is the entire React component tree for the page
     /*
       to remove styled components:
       1. remove const sheet
       2. remove StyleSheetManager
       3. remove sheet.getStyleElement from setHeadComponents array
     */
     const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
     const ApolloQueries = (
       <ApolloProvider client={client}>
         <StyleSheetManager sheet={sheet.instance}>
           {bodyComponent}
         </StyleSheetManager>
       </ApolloProvider>
     );
     // getDataFromTree walks ApolloQueries tree for all Apollo GQL queries
     // It runs the queries and mutates client object
     getDataFromTree(ApolloQueries).then(() => {
       // renders ApolloQueries to string and then inserts it into the page
       replaceBodyHTMLString(renderToString(ApolloQueries))
       // sets head components with styled components and apollo state
       setHeadComponents([sheet.getStyleElement(), makeApolloState(client)])
       resolve();
     })
   })
```

The error it shows

```
index.js:2177 Warning: Failed context type: The context `client` is marked as required in `Query`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Query (at allCars.js:105)
    in div (at allCars.js:81)
    in div (at allCars.js:78)
    in CarTemplatePage (created by ComponentRenderer)
    in ComponentRenderer (created by Route)
    in Route (created by Layout)
    in div (at index.js:24)
    in div (at index.js:9)
    in Layout (at index.js:6)
    in _default (created by ComponentRenderer)
    in ComponentRenderer (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(ComponentRenderer))
    in withRouter(ComponentRenderer) (created by Root)
    in ScrollContext (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(ScrollContext))
    in withRouter(ScrollContext) (created by Root)
    in Router (at root.js:151)
    in DefaultRouter (created by Root)
    in Root (at app.js:51)
    in AppContainer (at app.js:50)

I just want to render out the data coming from a csv file
```

i have also created the client object but it still is undefined how can i resolve this issue. And also i know that the gatsby does not officially support apollo but i want to run queries in my component hence i need to use apollo found the gatsby ssr file hack in github. Please help and thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to Gatsby V2, `StaticQuery` component is similar to **Apollo Client**.

Example from https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/#basic-example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query HeadingQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <header>
        <h1>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
      </header>
    )}
  />
);
```

Comment: can it be used to query based on events like onclick??